# Disable variable value information in chrome debugger

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image]

I don't know where or what key combination could make to enable variable value viewer inside the file viewer.
How to disable ? (I dont see the way...?)

Comment: Do you want to enable our disable? And why the blur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called "display variable values inline while debugging". You can turn it off in the "Settings > Preferences > Sources" options under the DevTools menu.

[image]

This might help too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a9rK.jpg